# How to install with wubi without internet connection

Tags: wubi

If I place wubi.exe and iso of same version in a single folder then is it possible to install ubuntu. My problem is that I have no broad band connection can I install ubuntu with windows installer?

Answer (score 0):

No, Windows Installer won't help. Instead, mount the ISO with the Virtual CD-ROM Control Panel, a free add-on direct from Microsoft. http://www.neowin.net/news/microsoft-releases-tool-to-mount-isos-for-windows-xp-vista-and-7 has more details.